# Kendo-ui custom error message

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

Is it possible to change the apperance of an kendo validation error message? I don't want to display error messages as:

[image: default error message in kendo-ui]

I'd like to show the error message as a tooltip. The exclamation-sign should be red and after hover, the error message should be displayed. But as you can see the default message format from kendo is displayed.

[image]

the glyphicon is from bootstrap. The solution can be written using Kendo or angularJS.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: will proceed once you shared the code snippet !

Comment: Yes. Overwrite Kendo's styles with your own.

Answer (score 0):

Kendo UI Validator has option to set errorTemplate for custom validation indicators.

```
$("#myform").kendoValidator({
    errorTemplate: "<span class='custom-error'>#=message#</span>"
});
```

Your html

```
<form id="myform">
    <input name="username" required /> <br />
    <button>Validate</button>
</form>
```

In style definitions you can define your own styles

```
.custom-error {
    color: red;
}
```